# ¿Como descargar e instalar automaticamente un apk desde código java?

Tags: android, apk

¿Cómo puedo descargar e instalar un apk desde código java, que se encuentra en un servidor cualquiera, de forma automática?

Answer (score 1):

Si la aplicación esta previamente instalada firmada y proviene de Google Play Store, la actualización puede realizarse automaticamente, esto si se tiene activada la opción de "Auto-update":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Si piensas descargar y lograr que se instale automáticamente esto no es posible**, el usuario debe permitir su instalación y aceptar los permisos, la razón es principalmente evitar instalación de aplicaciones que puedan realizar daños como un malware.

Comment: Si, en mi caso por ser de un origen desconocido, el S.O me indica que debo de aceptar la instalación, tiene razón. Y es que si el usuario no acepta la instalación, el apk queda en las descargas, y no sé como borrarlo si el usuario no acepta la instalación. Para que no quede el apk ahí....

Comment: Por que eso ya es un evento del S.O y no de mi app..

Comment: Incluso un evento antes de lo que menciono, y que no puede ser automatizado es precisamente **habilitar la instalación de "Fuentes desconocidas", lo cual programaticamente no puede ser realizado.**

Comment: Bueno en ese caso la app indica que deben de activar el Origen de fuentes desconocidas para poder recibir actualizaciones. Sin embargo creo que está dificil evitar que los usuarios consigan el APK que quedó descagado..

Comment: Igual le agradezco mucho por su tiempo!!

Comment: @Wayner cuando el .apk es descargado, se genera una notificación la cual al dar clic pueden aprobar su instalación.

Comment: Si, pero si no se aprueba igual queda el apk en la carpeta de descarga...